# won't start new row on txt to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to both php and mysql.  I have a txt file with a table on it that has each column seperated by a semi-colon `column1;column2` and each row is on a new line in the txt file.

> column1-row1;column2-row1
>
> column1-row2;column2-row2

I am trying to upload the txt file to a mysql table using phpmyadmin.  The first row goes in just fine, but the second one doesn't.  I have tried `\r` and `\n` and also `\r\n` but none of these are working.  Those only drop the second result on the txt file to another line (not row) on the first mysql row.  So everything is going into the first row on the mysql table.

I have also tried putting a semi-colon after the last column as well `column1;column2;` but all this does is stop after the fist row.

I guess I am asking how I format the txt file to make each line on the txt file start a new row in the sql table.  Or maybe I need to set something up on phpmyadmin first. This is probably extremely easy, but again, I am very new to both php and sql.  Thanks so much.

---

Okay, It's the same issue I originally had.  I have a database, and in that database I have a table with two columns 'a' and 'b'.  I also have a txt file I created already that has 50 rows of data.  On the txt file, I have seperated 'a' and 'b' with a semicolon a;b and then I have hit return on my keyboard to make the next row of data.  When I upload the txt file using either SQL or your PHP script and then browse the table on my database, it has only entered the first row from my txt file and after the 'b' in the first row (on my database table), it has started to enter the second row of data (from my txt file) on a new line but still the same row.  I would like the second from my txt file to be placed in a new row on my database table.  Maybe I can't, but that's the problem I am having.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
                                
$user_name = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";
$server = "server";
                                
                                
                                
$db = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
            
            
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$fileHandle = fopen('my_text_file.txt', 'rb');

while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
    $cols  = explode(';', fgets($fileHandle));
    $query = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO database_table (field1_name, field2_name) VALUES ("%s", "%s")',
        $cols[0], $cols[1]
    );

    mysql_query($query);
}

fclose($fileHandle);
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

And my txt file looks like this:

```
a;b
c;d
e;f
```

Comment: The problem is right there - "using phpmyadmin". Stop. Get the command-line out, and load it using LOAD DATA INFILE. phpmyadmin should not be used for anything, ever. It is a data destruction tool.

Comment: $please post the source code you're currently using now otherwise it will nearly impossible to help you at this point if my current answer didn't help _already_. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I just read your recent edit. Thanks for posting more details. That is much clearer now.. Unfortunately it's going to be hard to _reproduce_ your error. I will try to create a similar text file and then I will try to insert it into my database using PHP. I will post the contents of the text file and working script when I finish.

Comment: [SOLVED] I found out that if I use notepad++ to create the txt file, it would create the problem I was having.  But if I create it in notepadd++ and then open it in text editor and save it, it works just like I would like it to.  I guess it is adding formatting in notepad++.  Thank you so much for all your help and work trying to help me out.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\yourfile.txt'
INTO TABLE yourtable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

And then click the submit (go) button.

EDIT: If you go the PHP route, try this:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$fileHandle = fopen('yourfile.txt', 'rb');

while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
    $cols  = explode(';', fgets($fileHandle));
    $query = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO yourtable (column1, column2) VALUES ("%s", "%s")',
        $cols[0], $cols[1]
    );

    mysql_query($query);
}

fclose($fileHandle);
mysql_close($db);
```

It should work assuming each "row" is separated by a newline in the text file.

Comment: I tried that and I got this error `#1045 - Access denied for user 'username'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Do you have GRANT permissions for your database?

Comment: I should, I am the one that created it.  Where would I check that?

Comment: Click Home, then click Privileges. Next, find your user and click the edit icon/button.  For ease sake, just click where it says "Check All" toward the top where it says "Global Privileges" and then click Go. Make sure your password is correct, too!

Comment: I guess I am not seeing any of that.  I use 1and1 as a host and am therefor using their portal.  It's fairly simple, there is a home icon, which when clicked on, it takes me to the MYSQL-CONTROL-CENTER where I can change the language, but that's about it.  Back on 1and1 is where I can change my password for my database.

Comment: OH! Therein lies your problem, the file is stored locally while your MySQL server is remote.  You would need to upload the txt file to that server and then change the path of `C:\\yourfile.txt` to `/path/to/yourfile.txt`.  That might work..

Comment: Okay, I think you lost me.  I thought I knew what you meant, so I uploaded the file to my host via ftp, then I tried the command line again but with the path to my file set up as you stated and still received the same error.  Do you think doing this through php would be easier and less of a hassle?

Comment: Totally. Do you know how to do that? Or do you want me to post a sample script to get you started?

Comment: I could probably search for different code sample and piece them together, but if you would be able to do that, that would be incredible.  Thank you so much for all the help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much.  New line meaning \n or just a carriage return while creating the txt file?

Comment: I set this up and it seems to be doing the same thing.  It doesn't start a new row, it just puts a line break on the current row and then ends when it runs out of characters.

Comment: _What_ doesn't seem to start a new "row?" Are you saying that it's not inserting a new row into the db or something that GENERATES the text file is making a new row? Because your questions should be specific. If the problem _now_ is that your text file isn't being generated correctly then we're not dealing with not one but `two` issues.  They are independent of each other.  Still, none of that means my script won't work just because the text file isn't being generated correctly (if that's the case.) To answer your question: yes you need to have a new line after each row in the text file.

Comment: Try using the constant PHP_EOL.  If you're using PHP to generate the text file you could say something like `echo $row . PHP_EOL;` and that will make a new line character.  Is this resolved yet?  We can't keep going back and forth on the comments here, that is discouraged on stack overflow...